# iOS App - UI on iPad for iPhone only app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, user-interface

I'm working on an iPhone based App. It works fine on all devices and looks fine on all iPhone models, but for the iPad blown up version, there's less space above the UI than I'd like (some of the buttons are cut off by the edge of the screen where they weren't before.

I've uploaded some screenshots to make this clearer). The UI still functions fine, but visually it bugs me a bit so I was wondering if there's anything I can do about it that doesn't involve converting it into a Universal App. Is there anything that could be causing it?

I just did a test using:

```
NSLog(@"RESOLUTION = %@", NSStringFromCGSize([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size));
```

For screen resolution of the scalable iPhone App on the iPad, and it's the same result for iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) and for the iPad based on the simulator. The code I'm running should be the same for both devices, so I'm wondering if the status bar could be the culprit. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

Actually, it seems like its just limited to iPad retina, although that still doesn't rule out the status bar. I'll try accounting for that and see if that makes some difference.

### iPhone screenshots are as following:

[image: iphone1]
[image: iphone2]

### iPad screenshots are as following:

[image: ipad1]
[image: ipad2]

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout for your UI objects's placement, or do you do this manually (with code) ? In the case of coding, how do you check which structure to use?

Comment: I'm doing it manually. I'm basically checking if screen dimensions are good for iPhone 4-inch models, and setting the UI up one way for that, otherwise I'm setting it up for 3.5-inch models and iPad-scalable. Setting it up to do something different for the iPad UI shouldn't be huge problem though. I'd just need to know the root cause.

Comment: why there is a black spaces there? is that the 2X effect on iPad?

Comment: in this case why do you care any way? that looks bad anyway. better to support iPad

Comment: maybe its also under the status bar in the iPhone screenshot but because its transparent. while in the iPad its 2x and status bar is no top. try to remove the status bar. and check results

Comment: Yes, it's using the 2X effect in the iPad screenshot. Probably just supporting iPad would be a clearer cut fix and the most sensible option. My main goal with this app is to get it out there for iPhone 5 as something I could show for job interviews after college. In the end, there is the question of why do subpar quality for iPad at all. I guess my thinking is a)supporting all devices at least somewhat well is good in industry anyway and b)iPhone 6 or later may be in the future/already out when I've release this, which may have another new screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was the status bar height that was causing the problem. I'll probably update this answer shortly with the complete solution I ended up with since removing the status bar on the iPad seems like the way to go regardless of whether or not there is a retina display for said iPad.